# How to use different staticfiles location based on if it is development or production server

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

This is my `settings.py`:

```
import os
import sys
SECRET_KEY = 'secrit'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

RUNNING_DEVSERVER = (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'runserver')
if RUNNING_DEVSERVER:
    DEBUG = True
else:
    DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'ebdjangoapp-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com']


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'ebdjangoapp',
    'storages',
)


AWS_HEADERS = {  # see http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
        'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=94608000',
    }

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'ebdjangoappstaticfiles'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'secritkey'

# Tell django-storages that when coming up with the URL for an item in S3 storage, keep
# it simple - just use this domain plus the path. (If this isn't set, things get complicated).
# This controls how the `static` template tag from `staticfiles` gets expanded, if you're using it.
# We also use it in the next setting.
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'

# This is used by the `static` template tag from `static`, if you're using that. Or if anything else
# refers directly to STATIC_URL. So it's safest to always set it.
if RUNNING_DEVSERVER:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
else:
    STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)

# Tell the staticfiles app to use S3Boto storage when writing the collected static files (when
# you run `collectstatic`).
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'ebdjangoapp.custom_storages.StaticStorage'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'ebdjangoapp.custom_storages.MediaStorage'


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ebdjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "ebdjangoapp/static/templates/")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ebdjango.wsgi.application'


if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    # Default Django
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

I follwed this URL https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/ to let Amazon server my static and media files. It works perfectly on production. I decided to stop my production server until I fully test everything on development.

I thought these lines in my `settings.py` file:

```
RUNNING_DEVSERVER = (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'runserver')
# ...
if RUNNING_DEVSERVER:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
else:
    STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
```

would allow my development server to look for static files in the static folder in the app directory. I did `python manage.py runserver` and went to `127.0.0.1` and when I inspect element, these errors are shown:

```
GET https://ebdjangoappstaticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/home.js 
home:11 GET https://ebdjangoappstaticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/bootstrapCSS/css/bootstrap.min.css 
home:12 GET https://ebdjangoappstaticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/bootstrapJS/bootstrap.min.js 
home:15 GET https://ebdjangoappstaticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/home.css
```

When I try to import the CSS files I do it like this in my template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}">
```

What else do I have to change so that it doesn't search `https://ebdjangoappstaticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com` for my static files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with your `if` statement, however, your argv approach is *very* fragile. For example, you could run the same script with `python manage.py runserver` or `manage.py runserver`, changing the argument order and breaking your logic.

Instead, there are two more sturdy approaches you can use; The easiest it to use the `DEBUG` setting to determine if you're in development or production.

```
if DEBUG:
    # assume we're local
else:
    # otherwise assume we're in production
```

Then you just need to make sure you set `DEBUG = False` in production, which is something you should be very careful about doing anyways.

If you have multiple environments, such as a QA server, staging server and production servers, it's wise to use an environment variable and import that into your settings.

```
import os

# get environment variable ENV from the system
# default to prod if it doesn't exist
ENV = os.getenv('ENV', 'prod')

if ENV == 'local':
    # use local settings
elif ENV == 'stage':
    # use staging settings
else:
    # assume we're in prod
```

You can then set the `ENV` environment variable in each of your environments to match their role (`local`, `dev`, `qa`, `stage`, `prod`, etc). This way you don't need to alter your settings files to flip variables.

One last handy trick is you can cascade your settings files by selectively importing them based on a variable.

```
ENV = os.getenv('ENV', 'prod')

SOME_SETTING = 'no.png'

if ENV == 'local':
    import settings_local # could override SOME_SETTING
else:
    import settings_prod # could also override SOME_SETTING
```

Comment: Okay thanks. So in my situation, how come it is still checking `https://ebdjangoappstaticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com` for static files even though I have `if RUNNING_DEVSERVER: STATIC_URL = '/static/'` (I also put a `print('dev')` statement inside the `if` statement and verified that it does enter the `if` statement).

Comment: Your argv approach is very fragile since the arguments can change fairly easily `python mange.py runserver` vs `manage.py runserver` if you have python files automatically run. I've updated the answer with this info.

Comment: Right, but I'll always be running the dev server with `python manage.py runserver` and if it is run in any other way, `DEBUG` will always be `False`. And since I don't run production with `python manage.py runserver`, I felt this is secure, right? But regarding the current issue, even though Django knows that I am running with dev server (or so I think, because I placed an `if` statement inside `if RUNNING_DEVSERVER: STATIC_URL = '/static/'` and it does get executed), it still checks `https://ebdjangoappstaticfiles.s3.amazonaws.com` for static files (instead of local files). Any idea why?

Comment: It will break in all sorts of different ways, but if you insist on doing it that way, `print sys.argv[1]` to see what your settings file thinks the argument is. It most likely isn't picking it up correctly.

Comment: Also, setting an environment variable is easy. It won't change how your production code runs since if the ENV variable is missing on the system it'll just default to `prod`.

Comment: Okay I'll try your way, where exactly do I set the environment variable `ENV`? (trying to set it to `ENV = dev`)

Comment: You don't set it in code, you set it in your operating system. Google it; There are plenty of tutorials on how to do set them in Windows, Linux and OSX.

Comment: I'm using this methodology and it's working fine.  However, when I run collectstatic, Django is pushing my staticfiles to "c:/static/" and not to my production staticfiles location.  Is there a way to make collectstatic to automatically move files to the storage location (Azure in my case).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. All you need to do is to set STATICFILES_STORAGE.

```
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
    STATIC_URL = "/static/"
else:
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = "backend.storage_backends.StaticStorage"
    STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_STATIC_LOCATION)
```